# Configure an Oracle DB to assume double byte character sets by default

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, mono, centos

I have set up an Oracle DB with AL32UTF8. I am able to put DBCS characters (chinese, high-ascii, etc.) in the DB when using a tool such as SQLPlus and SQLDeveloper.

However, when my application, which is using the Oracle Instant Client, attempts to put data into the DB, DBCS characters are turned into ? marks. I was able to solve this issue and get things working by doing this: export NLS_LANG='.AL32UTF8' on the machine (CentOS) running my application. The DB is on a separate machine. With the above fix, I would need to set NLS_LANG on all clients.

What I want to be able to do (if possible) is configure the DB so that it assumes the client is using NLS_LANG = '.AL32UTF8' by default, so that NLS_LANG does not have to be set on all clients. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

This settings belongs to client only, if client assume that default is some latin, you can't override it somewhere else.
On the other hand, you can always do `ALTER SESSION` to set required`NLS_LANG` option in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up an `AFTER LOGON` trigger is the only way for the database layer to positively control NLS parameters.  Settings inherited via the client environment will override those set in the server environment.